# Does the "AlternatingItemTemplate" work in windows explorer 9?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css

The following code with alternating background I have shows up fine in Chrome and Firefox but not IE9:
If IE9 does support it, what am I missing?

[image]

Here is the output in Chrome and in IE9 respectively. Notice the grayish background missing on IE9

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer, or any other browser for that matter,  has no knowledge of `AlternatingItemTemplate`. It's part of a server-side control. ASP.NET *renders* the `AlternativeItemTemplate`'s contents when it's an alternate row.

As far as your background color not working, I recommend using the [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and tracing the style to determine why it isn't visible.

Comment: Thanks! But how does it explain not showing up on IE9 when it shows up in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @user1266515 It doesn't explain it fully, but it does tell you that it is not the `AlternatingItemTemplate`. You either have a CSS problem, or something else. The Developer Tools, as mentioned above, should help you figure out the exact problem (Perhaps another CSS class is overriding your background color)

Comment: I agree and would only add that what you would want to start to review would be the rendered HTML source of the page, and not the asp.net code.  The rendered source will tell you more about what's going on with this problem than the asp.net will.

Comment: post your rendered HTML and we could review that with you as well.

Comment: @user1266515 the images don't really help. The actual markup might, but it might not. I would encourage you to use the Developer Tools instead since you have access to all of the resources needed to solve the problem.